# How do I join a table against itself (via a relational table)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Consider the following tables:

people:

```
id: integer
name: string
```

friends:

```
id1: integer
id2: integer
```

I want to find all pairs of friends, so I use something like this:

```
People.joins("JOIN friends ON friend.id1 = people.id JOIN friends ON friend.id2 = people.id")
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" 
JOIN friends ON friends.id1 = people.id 
JOIN people ON friends.id2 = people.id
```

And the following error:

```
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "people" specified more than once
```

What's wrong with specifying `people` more than once?

Comment: Try `... join people p on friends.id2 = p.id`. You have two People tables in your query and need to distinguish them. What do your `People` and `Friend` models look like? Specifically the `belongs_to` and `has_many`, etc, statements? Those would normally take care of simple joins for you.

Comment: @lurker Thanks but now I'm getting a completely different error. :-/

Comment: See my updated comment. You should be using the Rails models facilities for simplicity where you can (which is part of the point of using Rails :)). What different error are you seeing? What new error did you see?

Comment: I posted the new error in the comments below. I don't think it's a Rails model issue because I get the same error when I execute raw SQL against Postgres.

Comment: Never mind, there was an error my updated SQL. It works now. :)

Comment: I'm not saying it's a Rails model issue. I'm saying you could be using the Rails model directives to achieve this in a more Rails-like way rather than explicitly writing the SQL joins.

Comment: @lurker Thanks! I figured out the Rails-y way too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them different aliases:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM people p1
JOIN friends ON friends.id1 = p1.id 
JOIN people p2 ON friends.id2 = p2.id
```

Comment: Thanks but now I get this error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "friends"............ LINE 1: ...friends.id1 = people.id JOIN people p2 ON friends...

Comment: @BarryFruitman ok... did you include a "FROM" clause in your query? What does your new query look like?

Comment: Never mind. There was an error in my updated SQL. Your solution works. :)